# Get a list of relations ordered by pivot field in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, dynamics-al

Basically I have users who belongs to many users. We can imagine friendship relations between users.

So I have a pivot table for the relation, with the id's of 2 users and one additionnal field 'created_at'.

---

**users table**: id, name

**friend_user table** : user_id, friend_id, created_at

---

**In my User model**, i have a friends function which returns a collection of users :

```
public function friends() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friend_user', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}
```

My goal is to get the list of every relation between users. With a loop on User::all(), I can easily get all those relations, user after user :

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
   foreach ( $user->friends as $friend ) {
       return [$user->name . 'is friend with ' . $friend->name];
   }
}
```

But I would like to get them ordered by 'created_at', indifferently the user who is in the relation.

Is there an easy way to do this with eloquent or maybe another way ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot table fields with the alias `pivot`

```
$user = User::with(['friends' => function($friendQuery) {
    $friendQuery->orderBy('pivot.created_at', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

Comment: Return a SQLState "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot.created_at' in 'order clause'". What does return this query for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with
`User::orderBy('created_at')->get();`
or if you reffer to relation, you can do the same in the relationship

```
public function friends() {
return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friend_user', 'user_id', 'friend_id')->orderBy('created_at');}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this function returns me the friends of 1 user, and I need to get all the rows of the friend_user table, not just those refering of a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

may be this helps to you first change your function into this

```
    public function friends() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Friend::class);
}
```

then in controler do this

```
$users = User::with('friends')->get();
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
   
       return [$user->name . 'is friend with ' . $user->firends->name];
     }
```

use dd($users) to check whether you find a friends relation or not.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have friends table or Friend model. Just users belonging to users